# Sharepoint Workflow Email Notification

Tags: workflow

Am unable to insert a table and border to it into a sharepoint workflow body..When i try to do that the format of the table is changing.Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you creating the table using HTML script?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your workflow's send email step, a screenshot of what the table looks like, and a detailed description of what the table is supposed to look like versus what it currently looks like.

Answer (score 1):

In SPD workflow,select the drop down on "Send an Email",select "Properties".Click the textbox against the "Body" field and add your table design as HTML script.Make sure you don't leave any space(between tags) in the HTML script.Which means your HTML script should not be aligned and should be a run through text without any space

Answer (score 1):

When I need a HTML-formatted email body, I create a string variable to hold the HTMl, then I set the body of the workflow email equal to my variable. I'm including an example of html containing a table with custom CSS. I've enclosed the entire body within a div and refer to that div for all of my CSS properties. This keeps SharePoint's master pages/CSS from overriding your CSS. It's important to note that there are no spaces in the HTML.

[image]